# Bootstrap Nav Menu active link indicator

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that I am working on in wordpress using parallax scrolling and bootstrap V 2.3.2.

I have two questions regarding the nav menu bar:

- Can anyone offer some suggestions on getting the nav bar to stay at the top of the page when I scroll back to the top?
- This is related to above question. When I scroll to the top and go back to the "home section"
  the second section "Creative Services" is still highlighted even though that is not the active page. I would like to have it return to it's normal (white) state.

[Link to my website](http://www.mexicocityamsterdam.com)

Comment: it seems you are using third party plugins for parallax scrolling. Please give info or link for those in your question.

Comment: I belive the programer who helped me set up the site used Waypoint.